# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 black screen / freeze

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, amd-graphics

I am running:

Windows 8 Pro with Media Center 64bit
990FXA-GD80 (MS-7640)
AMD FX 8150 Eight-Core Processor x64
Two AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series 
32 GB RAM

I have installed Windows on primary HDD.
I have installed Wubi on secondary HDD.

Windows detects Ubuntu 14.04 and offers an option to boot either OS.
I pick Ubuntu to finish install.
Computer restarts.

GNU Grub comes up with options to install as normal mode, safe graphic mode, ACPI workarounds, Verbose mode, and Demo mode.

Also the option to access the grub> and edit boot options via E key.

I have entered entered: nomodeset, radeon.modeset=0, radeon.modeset=1

All attempt to install Ubuntu have resulted in either a black screen with monitor saying no signal, or Ubuntu logo, purple background and white dots blinking from left to right then the gui freezes and I still have the use of mouse.

My goal posting here is to acquire the information to install Ubuntu via terminal / text only so that I can install video drivers after the install.

I have the Linux video drivers on the hdd that I am using to install, so implementing the video drivers before the install from the GNU Grub "grub>" command line.

I will also consider using VBox to install then from inside guest to install into psychical hdd.

Any options or ideas I will love you forever!

Comment: The [Minimal-CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) uses a text based installation.

Comment: maybe you should write what you did as an answer and accept it.

Comment: When I posted my edit I didn't have the points to answer questions.

Comment: With Ubuntu Server 14.04 , Fglrx did not come installed. I didn't need to clean or uninstall before I installed the drivers. It was a smooth install. Server also has the option to network install Ubuntu Desktop, I did not use that option, as I needed the video drivers first.

Answer (score 1):

1. I installed Ubuntu Server 14.04
2. Installed video drivers
3. Installed Ubuntu Desktop

Fixed my own problem.

Someone also informed me that the Minimal-CD will also provide a text based installation.

Comment: it's not provide as answer to this question.